# how to fill the cpu ram

Tags: python-2.7

Any help on how do we fill the CPU RAm of the system??

I wanted to play around filling my cpu ram and see the behavior. machine is in linux OS.

I got a link from one of the forum previous questions but I do not know how to use it. http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html

I am not getting proper stuff from here..

I have heard from one of my friend to use malloc but need some direction on this...

Any help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking to do is [stress testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing). There are various programs for your operating system that will do this for you.

Some linux options:

- [Memory Stress Test](http://freecode.com/projects/stress)
- [Full on testing suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=pts_desktop_live)

There are links to other options [here](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=486495).

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer if you don't need any further help!

Comment: I have already commented saying thanks for help. If I would have some doubt, I would have commented on that.